# cMake find_package Python

Tags: python, cmake

I try to create multiple cMake targets using different versions of Python. In my cMakeLists I define the `Python_ROOT` variable and use `find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)` to get the python library path, version and linking options.

Is it possible to undo the find_package and call `find_package(..)` a second time? Something like the code snipped bellow. Right now, I get to times the same python version.
In the final version, the user should define a list of python paths when calling cMake.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)   # set version string with project() command
cmake_policy(SET CMP0094 NEW)   # use LOCATION for Python lookup strategy
cmake_policy(SET CMP0074 NEW)

# Project 
project(Test
    VERSION 1.0.0 
)

set(Python_FIND_STRATEGY LOCATION)

# Python 3.5
set(Python_ROOT "<PATH to 3.5>" CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)

message("*****************************************")
message("Python_ROOT " ${Python_ROOT})
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

message("Python_FOUND " ${Python_FOUND})
message("Python_Interpreter_FOUND " ${Python_Interpreter_FOUND})
message("Python_Development_FOUND " ${Python_Development_FOUND})
   
message("Python_LIBRARIES " ${Python_LIBRARIES})
message("Python_LIBRARY_DIRS " ${Python_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Python_INCLUDE_DIRS " ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("Python_LINK_OPTIONS " ${Python_LINK_OPTIONS})
message("Python_EXECUTABLE " ${Python_EXECUTABLE})
message("Python_INTERPRETER_ID " ${Python_INTERPRETER_ID})
  
message("Python_VERSION " ${Python_VERSION})
message("Python_VERSION_MAJOR " ${Python_VERSION_MAJOR})
message("Python_VERSION_MINOR " ${Python_VERSION_MINOR})
message("*****************************************")

# target A definition

# Python 2.7
set(Python_ROOT "<PATH to 2.7>" CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)

message("*****************************************")
message("Python_ROOT " ${Python_ROOT})
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)

message("Python_FOUND " ${Python_FOUND})
message("Python_Interpreter_FOUND " ${Python_Interpreter_FOUND})
message("Python_Development_FOUND " ${Python_Development_FOUND})
   
message("Python_LIBRARIES " ${Python_LIBRARIES})
message("Python_LIBRARY_DIRS " ${Python_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Python_INCLUDE_DIRS " ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("Python_LINK_OPTIONS " ${Python_LINK_OPTIONS})
message("Python_EXECUTABLE " ${Python_EXECUTABLE})
message("Python_INTERPRETER_ID " ${Python_INTERPRETER_ID})
  
message("Python_VERSION " ${Python_VERSION})
message("Python_VERSION_MAJOR " ${Python_VERSION_MAJOR})
message("Python_VERSION_MINOR " ${Python_VERSION_MINOR})
message("*****************************************")

# target B definition
```

**Edit:**
The output of the script above is:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29910.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.28.29910.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29910/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
*****************************************
Python_ROOT C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35
-- Found Python: C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35/python.exe (found version "3.5.2") found components: Interpreter Development
Python_FOUND TRUE
Python_Interpreter_FOUND TRUE
Python_Development_FOUND TRUE
Python_LIBRARIES C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35/libs/python35.lib
Python_LIBRARY_DIRS C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35/libs
Python_INCLUDE_DIRS C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35/include
Python_LINK_OPTIONS
Python_EXECUTABLE C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py35/python.exe
Python_INTERPRETER_ID Canopy
Python_VERSION 3.5.2
Python_VERSION_MAJOR 3
Python_VERSION_MINOR 5
*****************************************
*****************************************
Python_ROOT C:/Users/schnudi/.edm/envs/py27
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Python (missing: Interpreter Development) (found version
  "3.5")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython.cmake:347 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:44 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/schnudi/Desktop/temp/allinone/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```